# React app not appearing on live server (works locally) - No visible errors, suspect backend issue

Tags: reactjs, nginx, caching

Could use the wisdom of the crowd on this one. I just updated this React app, but like you can see on the page nothing appears. Here are the facts:

[Link to the app](https://fuguefoundation.org/dev/impact/) | [Code repo](https://github.com/fuguefoundation/ff-impact-calculator) (though I don't think the code is the issue)

1. The dev build works fine on localhost (`npm start`)
2. The production build works fine on a local server (`npm run build`)
3. If you look in the developer tools at the above link, you can see all the files are loading `200` in the browser, no errors in the console or `404`s.
4. The base href is set to `./`, which is correct given the app is in a subdirectory (and again, there are no console errors)
5. There is no cache set in the headers, and the static files themselves use [aggressive caching techniques](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/#static-file-caching). I have deleted the old files from the directory on the server and uploaded the production build, plus I checked the cache and `.conf` file on the nginx server for anything out of the ordinary.
6. This app was working last week at this URL (before I recently merged two pull requests), but the code changes were not to any of the component routing, and again, the app works fine on localhost and a local server.

So I feel like I'm missing something obvious and could use some other suggestions. I think the issue is on the backend, but I've hit a brick wall and could use a second set of eyes on it. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no route defined in your app that matches `/dev/impact`. If I manually push `/` to the history object your app renders the `HowRichAmIStandalone` component correctly on your production server.

I guess in development it works because your local development server serves the app e.g. at `localhost:3000/` and not `localhost:3000/dev/impact`. You need to [set the correct `basename` on the router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) in order for it to work:

```
<Router basename="/dev/impact">
    {/* ... */}
</Router>
```

You can also define the basename [in your env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) and only make it `/dev/impact` for the production environment if you don't want to have to type `localhost:3000/dev/impact` in development.

```
<Router basename={process.env.BASE_URL}">
    {/* ... */}
</Router>
```